# Pygame не может открыть аудио файл

Tags: python, файлы, pygame

Хочу получить длину аудио файла:

```
mixer.init()

def browse_file(self): 
    self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()

def show_details(self):
    sound = mixer.Sound(self.filename)
    total_length = sound.get_length()
    print(total_length)
```

При запуске программы возникает ошибка:

```
pygame.error: Unable to open file 'C:/Users/\u0410\u043d\u0442\u043e\u043d\u0438\u043d\u0430/Desktop/Music.mp3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что `mixer.Sound` может работать только с файлами форматов OGG или wav. Для того, чтобы проигрывать mp3-файлы необходимо использовать `pygame.mixer.music`

```
pygame.mixer.music.load(self.filename)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Однако в таком случае не получится получить длину файла. Это связано с тем, что [pygame.mixer.Sound](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound) загружает аудиофайл в выделенный под него буфер, а [pygame.mixer.music.load](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.load) проигрывает музыку из потока и не загружает файл в память целиком. Цитата из документации

> The difference between the music playback and regular Sound playback is that the music is streamed, and never actually loaded all at once.

Для того, чтобы получить длину файла можно воспользоваться модулем [mutagen](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/index.html). Тогда Ваша функция будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

def show_details(self):
    sound = MP3(self.filename)
    print(sound.info.length) # длина в секундах
```

В случае, если всё же хотите использовать `mixer.Sound` придётся сконвертировать файлы mp3 в OGG или wav.